# List of words in Hebrew

Tags: nlp, lexicon, resource-request, hebrew

Where can I found a list of all the words in Hebrew including plurals, inflections, etc.?
I have only found some lists that are based on wikipedia corpus or subtitles curpus, which include many errors and are missing so many words. (http://invokeit.wordpress.com/frequency-word-lists/)

Comment: I don't know Hebrew, but I suppose either it has irregular plurals, then they are listed in dictionaries. And if it has regular plurals, they should be derivable by one or multiple rules.

Comment: @Robert: Hebrew works differently from (Indo-European) languages: from a given consonantal root, you can form many different verbs, adjectives and nouns by particular (regular) patterns of vowel and prefixed or suffixed consonants: the list of possible forms of a root is huge. The verbs are particularly varied: there are several different patterns, and each pattern can inflect for number, gender and person of the subject and the object. But in practice, not all of these forms happen to exist for each root, so a real dictionary needs to list those that do.

Comment: @ColinFine I know some Arabic, and from you description of Hebrew plurals I presume plurals work in both languages in roughly the same way. All the Arabic dictionaries I have come across list irregular/semi-regular plurals (i.e. for all male nouns, and irregular feminine nouns; most feminine nouns have a regular plural). So I suppose Hebrew dictionaries would work the same way, because as you said, otherwise you would have hard time finding the correct plural.

Comment: @robert: Actually plurals are a bit simpler in Hebrew than Arabic, because only a few common words have broken plurals. My point was that plurals are only a small part of the morphology, especially the derivational morphology, of Hebrew (and Arabic), and that much of the morphology is not just adding suffixes, as most Indo-European morphology is.

Comment: There are languages with far more forms of a given word than is possible in Hebrew. I think some people feel that Hebrew blurs the boundary between derivation and inflection but I'm not sure that it does. I'm no Hebrew expert though and have not dabbled in some years now.

Comment: If you have a grasp of Arabic the challenges are much the same for Hebrew but there are enough major differences that it won't be totally straightforward either. Stuff like binyanim don't have anything like 1:1 mapping between the languages for instance.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned, which Hebrew you mean and what format you expect. Presuming, you are interested in the Modern Israeli Hebrew and that the format is not so important, the best choice would be (Hebrew-Hebrew) Even-Shoshan Dictionary: it includes both words in vocalized form and in ktiv male; plural and smikhut forms are provided for nouns, and basic inflected forms - for verbs.

There are scanned versions of the 1979-edition on the web and there is an [electronic version from babylon](http://store.babylon.com/product/dictionary/4742/7/7/1/1/1/The+Unabridged+Even-Shoshan+Dictionary), but it's for money.